# Correct way to approach INR currency in Java

Tags: java, number-formatting

I've this code for INR

```
long tenderedAmt = (long) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("en", "in")).parse(jAmtTenderedFormattedTextField.getText());`
```

But when I enter amount 00.50 that throwing exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

Using `Double`

```
Double tenderedAmt = (Double) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("en", "in")).parse(jAmtTenderedFormattedTextField.getText());
```

This snippet throws same exception.

Using

```
Double tenderedAmt = (Double) jAmtTenderedFormattedTextField.getText());
```

In above snippet if I've entered 1000.00 it suppose 1.00 instead thousand.
And throwing
`java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1,000.00"`
So how can I have approach currency in correct way?

Comment: you are trying to put your ammount into a long variable. use a double

Comment: I've explained what happening If I use double.

Comment: 00.50 is not valid long (integer). You'll need to prove your comments about doubles. They make no sense.

Comment: what is the full text you get from jAmtTenderedFormattedTextField.getText()

Comment: Gets double value that I've entered in  `jAmtTenderedFormattedTextField`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) the javadoc of `parse` method and this is what it says:

> Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a
>   number. The method may not use the entire text of the given string.

So, if we assign the result to `Number` type, it should give us the correct value, e.g.:

```
Number result = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("en", "in")).parse("1000.00");
System.out.println(result.doubleValue());
```

This should print `1000.0` as expected. Also, we don't need to `cast` this into any type. We can simply call `doubleValue()` or `longValue()` or any other `xxxValue()` to get the corresponding type.

If it prints `1.0` then I would recommend checking the value returned by `jAmtTenderedFormattedTextField.getText()`.

Comment: I've formatted  `jAmtTenderedFormattedTextField` correctly.

Comment: @SwapnilNagtilak can you sys out `jAmtTenderedFormattedTextField.getText()` and see what it prints?

Comment: Ok let me check.

Comment: Thanks code is working as I expected thank you so much for your time and efforts.